# convert three variable data into a date format in php

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

i have three variables containing values shown below

```
                       $day=13
                       $month=2
                       $year=2013
```

i want to convert these three variable data into a date format in php and store in anoother variable
Ho to do this??

Comment: $date = "$year:$month:$day" ?

Comment: `mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to handle this is to utilize [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class

```php
$date = new DateTime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't really have a date variable type, but it can handle time stamps; such a time stamp can be created with `mktime()`:

```
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

This can then be used with `date()` to format it:

```
$formatted = date('Y-m-d', $ts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will do the trick for you. Pass the date format as you need to the `date()` function.

```
echo date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

> O/P : Feb-13-2013

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$date_timestamp = strtotime($month . " " . $day . ", " . $year);
```

This returns a timestamp, which you can use to create a date:

```
$the_date = date("M d, Y", $date_timestamp);
```

However, if you just want a string of those dates:

```
$the_date = $month . " " . $day . ", " . $year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mktime() function

```
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0,$month, $day, $year);
```

then pass $ts to date function

```
$formatted = date('Y-m', $ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the most elegant way is using a datetime object, avoiding string concatenation:

**Parsing the date:**

```
$date = (new DateTime)->setDate($year, $month, $day);
```

**Zeroing time as well:**

```
$datetime = (new DateTime)->setDate($year, $month, $day)->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

**Formatting to string:**

```
$datestr = (new DateTime)->setDate($year, $month, $day)->Format('Y-m-d');
$datetimestr = (new DateTime)->setDate($year, $month, $day)->setTime(0, 0, 0)->Format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```